# Salesforce Managed package can't push

Tags: managed-package, apex-managed-sharing

I can't push managed package bcoz I've deleted few unwanted classes from it and rebuild the package now whenever I try to push this new uploaded package it went fail and ask me for deleted class bcoz it's still refer in previous organization so now I can't create new class with same name nor push to customer I am stuck.

Comment: Were the classes you cleaned up "global"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue in the past and order to fix I gone through the following steps -

1) Create a new managed patch version based on the installed version on subscribers org.
2) Update the removed classes with no code. Something like this

```
class ABC {

}
```

3) Remove all the references of the deleted classes from the code
4) Installed/Push the patch version on client/subscriber org
5) Now, install the version ( which you have already created in your package org ) and you will not see any error.

If you don't have patch org enabled, then please contact Salesforce support and explain the situation in a detailed manner and they will help you for sure!!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks naval its a great help . I make patch but no where i find push. how do it push it can i install through link and one more thing do i create managed package or beta version  in patch

Comment: Issue resolved @naval thanks for really great help at such a crucial time.